A confusion about Karnaugh Map
Consider the following four variable Boolean function:
$$F(A,B,C,D)=\sum(0,2,3,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,15)$$
If I show you the map, then what I get is:

I have marked the Essential Prime Implicants with a bluer shade, which is $BD$ and $B'D'$. Then if I consider the prime implicants, there are four that I can get, which is:

So basically, from these four ways, there can be four such combinations in which I can consider the 1's from these K-map, taking two at a time. Thus, the above Boolean function evaluates to the expression:
$$F=BD+B'D'+CD+AD$$
$$F=BD+B'D'+CD+AB'$$
$$F=BD+B'D'+B'C+AD$$
$$F=BD+B'D'+B'C+AB'$$
But, If I consider the zeros only to apply POS, instead of SOP, this is what I arrive at:

Now, the expression is:
$$F=(B'+D)(A+B+C+D')$$
$$=AB'+B'C+B'D'+AD+BD+CD$$
Now, there are few questions of mine. I can see that the expression from POS is simply the sum of all of the four expressions from SOP. Why is so? Does not it make the SOP expression more simplified than POS? If it does, why is not SOP a better alternative of POS? Moreover, why does POS make more terms here than SOP? They are supposed to be interchangeable.
I know it is usually disapproved to ask multiple questions on a single post at a time. But, the questions seem to be connected to each other.

From your SoP K-maps, you determined you have 4 redundant solutions.  All are equivalent, so either is minimum.  All are 4 2-input ANDs, 1 4-input OR and 2 NOTs.
From your PoS K-map, you found a single solution.  A 4-input OR, 2-input OR, 2-input AND and 2 NOTs.

Does not it make the SOP expression more simplified than POS?  ... Moreover, why does POS make more terms here than SOP? They are supposed to be interchangeable.

No, SoP or PoS are minimum and equivalent.  Aside from XORs (or XNORs) which exist outside of boolean algebra, anything you do to the equations SoP or PoS may destroy an optimum solution. SoP and PoS are interchangable.
I use may because there are things you can do which derive an equivalent solution.  Such as, doing deMorgan's on SoP converts it to all NANDs or doing deMorgan's on PoS converts it to all NORs.
You reintroduced the redundancy, when you converted the minimum PoSs into a redundant SoPs.  You have eliminated the minimization.  The six terms of your answer are all included in your four SoPs solutions.  There is overlap between SoP terms in your second K-map.  You are including non-essential prime implicants.
Proof:
First PoS solution: F=BD+B′D′+CD+AD - Either of the 4 could be used.
F=AB′+B′C+B′D′+AD+BD+CD
The terms AB' and B'C are missing from the first PoS solution, as in they are non-essential to this solution.  All terms from your initial two K-maps are included.
F = AB′ + B′C + B′D′ + AD + BD + CD
F = (B′D′ + CD + B′C) + (B′D′ + AD + AB′) + BD - Commutative & Idempotent
F = (B′D′ + CD + B′C (D' + D)) + (B′D′ + AD + AB′ (D' + D)) + BD - Compliment
F = (B′D′ + CD + B′CD' + B′CD) + (B′D′ + AD + AB′D' + AB′D) + BD - Distributive
F = (B′D′ (1 + C) + CD (1 + B′)) + (B′D′ (1 + A) + AD (1 + B') ) + BD - Distributive
F = B′D′ + CD + B′D′ + AD + BD - Identity
F = B′D′ + CD + AD + BD - Idempotent
F = BD + B′D′ + CD + AD - Rearranging to get PoS
Non-essential prime implicants are removed.
Consensus Law X Y + X' Z + Y Z = X Y + X' Z
Or using the Consensus Law, which is a tad trickier to follow.
F = AB′ + B′C + B′D′ + AD + BD + CD
F = (B′D′ + CD + B′C) + (B′D′ + AD + AB′) + BD - Commutative & Idempotent
F = B′D′ + CD + B′D′ + AD + BD - Consensus
F = B′D′ + CD + AD + BD - Idempotent
F = BD + B′D′ + CD + AD - Rearranging
Similarily, F=AB′+B′C+B′D′+AD+BD+CD can be manipulated with consensus to get all 4 SoP solutions by eliminating the appropriate non-essential prime implicants for the solution.
Laws and Theorems of Boolean Algebra
